# Typescript: private member is suddenly undefined

Tags: javascript, this, typescript, setinterval, private-members

So, I've got a basic Typescript application, that shouldn't actually cause any major problems, but it seems, that something's going wrong here and I have no idea what.

I do have this private member `minUpdateRate` in my `GameContainer` class, that is initialized in the constructor. This seems to go well, because when `GameContainer.start()` is called, the `console.log()` method will print out `1`.

However, when the `GameContainer.render()` method is called, it seems to be out of the scope or something, the log method outputs `undefined` there.

I'm pretty new to TypeScript and not that deep into JavaScript either (especially when it comes to scopes, it's getting confusing to me :/). How can I however solve this?

Main class:

```
class TwoDGame extends Game {
    public static main(context:CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        var game:Game = new TwoDGame();
        var container:GameContainer = new GameContainer(context, game);

        container.start();

        return game;
    }
}
```

Game Container class:

```
class GameContainer {
    ...
    private minUpdateRate:number;
    private game:Game;
    private time:number;
    ...

    constructor(context:CanvasRenderingContext2D, game:Game) {
        ...
        this.minUpdateRate = 1;
        this.game = game;
    }

    public start() {
        ...
        console.log(this.minUpdateRate);
    }

    public render() {
        var now:number = new Date().getMilliseconds();
        var delta:number = now - this.time;
        console.log(this.minUpdateRate);

        if (delta > this.minUpdateRate) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Render is called via setInterval in the script area:

```
var game = TwoDGame.main(context);

setInterval(game.getGameContainer().render, 16);
```

Comment: I can't see this method defined anywhere: `game.getGameContainer()`

Comment: `getGameContainer` is defined in `Game` super class

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/445528 . And congrats on asking the 1000th typescript question on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: To understand `this` a bit better in TypeScript : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're losing the object context when you pass `setInterval()` a reference to the "render" method that way.

```
setInterval(function() { game.getGameContainer().render(); }, 16);
```

There's no intrinsic relationship between a function and an object that refers to it via a property value. By using an anonymous function, you can ensure that the "container" object will be the value of `this` inside "render".

You could also do this with the `.bind()` method of the Function prototype:

```
setInterval(game.getGameContainer().render.bind(game.getGameContainer()), 16);
```

but that seems a little ugly in this case.