# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 - Timer event function to open model

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app, I want to launch a model every 10 minutes. In app.components.ts

I have simple function to launch this model.

```
openUpgradeModel() {
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(UpgradeToFullVersionModel);
modal.present();
}
```

How can I get that function to launch every 10 minutes or so?

Update, so I tried using an Observable.timer, however it loops over and over.

```
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    let timer = Observable.timer(2000,1000);
    timer.subscribe(t=> {
   UpgradeToFullVersionModel();
});
```

Is there anyway to tell if the model is already open don't fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to tell if the model is already open don't fire?

You can create a property in `app.component.ts` file

```
// Should be set to true the first time
private shouldShowModal: boolean = true;
```

Then set that property to false when showing the modal, but set it to true again when dismissing the modal:

```
openUpgradeModel() {
  let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(UpgradeToFullVersionModel);

  modal.onDidDismiss(() => {
    this.shouldShowModal = true;
  });

  this.shouldShowModal = false;

  // Show the modal
  modal.present();
}
```

And then, only show the modal if it's not being shown already:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  let timer = Observable.timer(2000,1000);
  timer.subscribe(t => {
    if(this.shouldShowModal) {
      this.openUpgradeModel();
    }
  });

//..
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, its much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need setInterval()

```
setInterval(() => { openUpgradeModal(); }, 1000 * 60 * 10);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829004/3221120